# HTTP Error 401 using Mechanize for Python scraping script

Tags: python, http, authentication, mechanize, login-script

I am writing a script to automatically scrape information from my companies directory website using mechanize. However, the interpreter returns **_response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required**  on`br.open(url)` when I run my script.
This is the portion of my code where the interpreter runs into the error.

```
from sys import path 
path.append("./mechanize/mechanize")
import _mechanize 
from base64 import b64encode 

def login (url, username, password):
    b64login = b64encode('%s:%s' % (username, password))
    br = _mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.addheaders.append(('Authorization','Basic %s' % b64login)) 
    br.open(url)
    r = br.response()
    print r.read()
```

The site I am trying to access is an internal site within my companies network, and it uses a GlobalSign Certificate for authentication on company-issued computers.

I am sure the authentication information I am inputting is correct, and I have looked everywhere for a solution. Any hints on how to resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a link to the website? It is really hard to answer that without having a look!

Comment: I am not allow to disclose that information for security reasons. But I can tell you that it is an internal site and it is not possible to access without being inside the company's network. If I run the code on a different network, the interpreter will return `[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your authentication methods don't match up.  You state that your company uses GlobalSign certificates but your code is using Basic authentication.  They are NOT equal!!

From a brief look at the [Mechanize documentation](http://www.polarhome.com:753/doc/python-mechanize/) (limited as it is), you don't implement authentication by manually adding headers.  It has it's own `add_password` method for handling authentication.

Also, as a general HTTP authentication policy, you should **NOT** use preemptive authentication by adding the authentication headers yourself.  You should set up your code with the necessary authentication (based on your library's documentation) and let it handle the authentication negotiation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!
I tried using the `add_password` method but I still recieve the same error. Do you have any other suggestions for a possible solution?

Comment: The only authentication methods that I see mentioned in their documentation (which you should be familiar with) are Basic and Digest.  It is quite possible that it doesn't support the authentication that you need.  You may have to find another library to use to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I have used the debugging tool in the browser class/curl and looking at the header, it is a Basic authentication ('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm = 'realm name'). I have tried passing the realm type (Basic) into the `add_password` method and have had no luck. Any other ideas on what the issue could be?

Comment: You should see a connection attempt without an authentication header value. The server should reject and respond with the `WWW-Authenticate` header response, one for each supported method. There should then be another attempt with the `Authorization` header set to match one of the required authentication methods.

Comment: This is the output I get:`send: 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: 'hostname'\r\nConnection: close\r\nAuthorization: Basic 'b64encoded_string'\r\nUser-
Agent: Python-urllib/2.7\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required\r\n'
header: Date: 'date'
header: Server: Apache
header: WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm='realm'
header: Content-Length: 533
header: Connection: close
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
header: Set-Cookie: 'cookie'`
Do you see anything that could be useful in figuring out the issue?

Comment: Did you remove the `br.addheaders.append()` method call in your code? Preemptive authentication is **NOT** recommended and may be breaking the authentication handshake, preventing the client from sending the next connection attempt after getting the 401 error response.

Comment: I tried using the `add_password()` method without the `br.addheaders.append()` and still no luck. I get all the same errors.

Comment: With the `br.addheaders.append()` removed, you should see the application perform the `GET` with no authentication headers.  The server will respond with a `401`.  Your application should then issue another `GET` with the authentication header.  This should all happen automatically on the `br.open()` call.  Are you seeing this?

Comment: If I remove all the authentication functions (`addheaders.append()` & `add_password()`), then I recieve a 104 error response with the following output: `send: 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: 'hostname'\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/2.7\r\n\r\n'`.

Comment: If you use just `add_password()`, you should see your client try to connect again, except it will contain the authentication headers.  If it doesn't try to connect, or doesn't validate, then this library won't work for you.